# Como criar validação para perguntar se o usuário quer mesmo sair da página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Tenho uma página onde o utilizador vai editar campos que estão num formulário. Esses dados vêm do banco de dados. O utilizador pode editá-los, no entanto, no fim ele pode gravar (ou seja, vai escrever/fazer update no banco de dados) ou então pode fechar.

Eu quero garantir que o utilizador, caso se engane e carregue noutro link de menu, ou carregue em retroceder a página seja questionado se quer sair da página sem carregar no botão salvar alterações?

Answer (score 2):

Crie um método para confirmar a saída da página, passando a url como parâmetro:

```js
function confirmar(url){
    event.preventDefault();  
    var resposta = confirm("Deseja mesmo sair da página?");
    if (resposta == true){
        location.top.href = url;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Depois coloque no atributo `onclick` da tag html.

Comment: nao entendi a parte de colocar onclick no atributo da tag html....
tenho que colocar isso em todos links? :S

Comment: sim, mais ou menos assim: <a href="index.html" onclick="confirmar('index.html')">Index</a>